# Get importlib directives from type library

Tags: com, portable-executable, com+, tlbinf32

How can one programmatically determine which type libraries (GUID and version) a given native, VB6-generated DLL/OCX depends on?

For background: The VB6 IDE chokes when opening a project where one of the referenced type libraries can't load one of its dependencies, but it's not so helpful as to say which dependency can't be met--or even which reference has the dependency that can't be met. This is a common occurrence out my company, so I'm trying to supplement the VB6 IDE's poor troubleshooting information.

Relevant details/attempts:

- I *do* have the VB source code. That tells me the GUIDs and versions as of a particular revision in the repo, but when analyzing a DLL/OCX/TLB file I don't know which version of the repo (if any--could be from a branch or might never have been committed to a branch) a given DLL/OCX corresponds to.
- I've tried using `tlbinf32.dll`, but it doesn't appear to be able to list imports.
- I don't know much about PE, but I popped open one of the DLLs in a PE viewer and it only shows `MSVBVM60.dll` in the imports section. This appears to be a special quirk of VB6-produced type libraries: they link only to `MSVBVM60` but have some sort of delay-loading mechanism for the rest of the dependencies.
- Even most of the existing tools I've tried don't give the information--e.g., depends.exe only finds `MSVBVM60.dll`.
- **However**: OLEView, a utility that used to ship with Visual Studio, somehow produces an IDL file, which includes the `importlib` directives. Given that VB doesn't use IDL files, it's clearly generating the information somehow. So it's possible--I just have no idea how.

Really, if OLEView didn't do it I'd have given it up by now as impossible. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: SImilar to whatever OLEView does, when you reference a COM DLL from a NET project, TLBIMP reads the TLB also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was conflating basic DLL functionality and COM. (Not all DLLs are COM DLLs.)

For basic DLLs, the Portable Executable format includes a section describing its imports. The Optional Header's directory 1 is about the DLL's imports. Its structure is given by `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`. [This](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/) is a starting point for learning about that.

COM DLLs don't seem to have an equivalent as such, but you can discover which other COM components its public interface needs: for each exposed interface, list out the types of their properties and their method arguments, and then use the Registry to look up where those types come from. `tlbinf32.dll` provides some of the basic functionality for listing members, etc. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985086.aspx)'s and intro to that.